# What is the use of _() in ruby/rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am looking at the source code of an program trying to figure out how it does certain things. One thing that caught my eye was the use of things like this in the views"
<%= _("Publish settings") %>
and in the controller:
flash[:notice] = _('Article was successfully created')

When I do _("Test") in the console it just returns "Test" string. So what is the use of the _() syntax. Haven't seen it before and can't find anything on google.
Any info will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It surely looks like some localization feature. As far as I can tell preferred method of doing that in Rails3 is `t` method, but if someone used external GetText gem for this purpose he might end up in such notation.

Comment: Thanks samuil, the program is Typo [link](https://github.com/fdv/typo/). It has one language file (dutch) but localization does not seem to be implemented. The string in the example does not match anything in the language file.